# Get Command Name

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to get the command name but it gives an error.
I don't know why it went wrong. Please help me.

error: Undefined variable 'testcommand1'

```
@commands.command(
    name='test'
)
async def testcommand1(self, ctx):
    json = {
        '_id': ctx.message.id,
        'command': str(testcommand1.name),
        'guild_id': str(ctx.guild.id),
    }
    await ctx.send(json)
```

Comment: `str(testcommand1.name)`  - where is `testcommand` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the command in a Cog, to get the command simply do `self.testcommand.name`
or you can get the command from the context, like so `ctx.command`

```py
command = ctx.command
name = command.name
```